# GWT Application in Desktop , tablet , Ipad

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have never worked on android.
I have to create a GWT/GXT web Application.

Will this application will look similar when viewed from Desktop, tablet(Windows/Android), Ipad.??

Comment: don't be worry on **GWT** , careful for your HTML and CSS designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response depend on how you have built your CSS. 
Did you use uibinder for HTML generation ?
It's all about how you build your html and how you add styles to our HTML. At the end GWT generates HTML elements for which you will apply your custom CSS. The way it will look like is dependent to you CSS files.
If you do nothing by default you should have the same rendering unless you use some third party components that handles internally a responsive design

Answer (score 3):

This is the point - similar yes - not identical

> "GWT shields you from worrying too much about cross-browser incompatibilities. If you stick to built-in widgets and composites, your applications will work similarly on the most recent versions of Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. (Opera, too, most of the time.)
>   
> Whenever possible, GWT defers to browsers' native user interface elements. For example, GWT's Button widget is a true HTML  rather than a synthetic button-like widget built, say, from a `<div>`. That means that GWT buttons render appropriately in different browsers and on different client operating systems
>   "

from [gwtproject.org](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBrowser.html)